# Loading new background image flickers on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, css, html

I am making a webpage for desktop and mobile. 
I have a div with a background image of bad quality.

```
div {  background-image: url(lowquality.jpg); background-size: cover; }
```

When going to that page I load a higher quality image to replace the lower one.

```
  let src = this.getHightQualitySrc();
  const imageToLoad = new Image();
  imageToLoad.onload = () => {
    div.setAttribute('style', `background-image: url(${src})`);
  };
  imageToLoad.src = src;
```

On desktop (windows) it works fine, when the high quality image is loaded it is replaced smoothly with no glitch.
Also on android it works fine. But on IOS on an Iphone when the high quality image is loaded you first see a white screen and the image loads again (starting with the top part of the image).

Can someone help me to have the same behaviour on IOS?

Comment: Have You tried to get this done with plain css using media-queries?

Comment: I don't have the url of the image in advance. I construct it in my JS

Comment: So you are telling me that you have one image in two states but the states change names dynamically and there is no way to counter this in css?

Comment: Indeed, I have no way to know in advance what the name will be